# Exportar en Xamarin Forms una tabla SQLITe a un emulador/dispositivo real

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, exportar, emulador

ojala puedan ayudarme puesto que es el final de mi proyecto, pero no tengo ni idea de como resolverlo
Les escribo porque en Xamarin Forms no sé como se exporta los datos de una tabla SQLITE a mi emulador (eso como 1º paso simplemente para saber que se exporta) y a por ejemplo el escritorio de la tablet que use mi Aplicacion una vez ya creada (o a donde sea). He probado varias cosas, no se si me pueden orientar con los errores recibidos:
Les envío codigo de donde se haya mi Base de Datos en la App.xaml.cs:

```html
public static SQLiteHelpers3 SQLiteBD3
        {
            get
            {
                if (db3 == null)
                {
                    db3 = new SQLiteHelpers3(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "JugadaAJugada.db5"));
                }
                return db3;
            }
        }
```

y mi  AndroidManifest (que por cierto cuando pedí los permisos es cuando me salió una advertencia que escribo literalmente: AndroidManifest.xml //uses-sdk/@android:targetSdkVersion '27' is less than $(TargetFrameworkVersion) ''. Using API-31 for ACW compilation)... no he querido tocar nada porque mi emulador es API27, y antes queria consultarles:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.dataplay_program" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <application android:label="DATAPLAY_PROGRAM.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@drawable/borrar"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Viendo este foro he creado un boton y he intentado seguir respuestas de ustedes, les paso códigos de los intentos:

```html
//Guardar copia de la base de datos

                    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "JugadaAJugada.db5");
                    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

                    //1º Intento:
                    string path1 = Path.Combine("/sdcard/", Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
                    var fileCopyName = string.Format(path1 + "/Database_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-tt}.db", DateTime.Now);

                    //2º Intento:
                    //var fileCopyName = string.Format("/storage/emulated/0/Database_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-tt}.db", DateTime.Now);
                    //var fileCopyName = string.Format("/sdcard/Database_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-tt}.db", DateTime.Now);

                    //3º Intento:
                    //var fileCopyName = string.Format("/Desktop/Database_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-tt}.db", DateTime.Now);

                    File.WriteAllBytes(fileCopyName, bytes);
```

Pero tengo estos problemas:
1º Intento: Me esta dando error diciendo que: 'Android' no contiene una definicion para 'OS' (pero en este mismo foro todo el mundo maneja esto sin problema), donde puede estar el error?

2º Intentos: en ambos casos me dice que el acceso esta denegado (en android manifest puse permisos)

3º intento: me dice que podria no encontrarse parte del camino (no se si es debido a que en el emulador no se puede exportar nada al escritorio pero si que puede ser valido en una tablet normal)

Muchisimas gracias de antemano por su ayuda!!